# Build Error : expected a property attribute before 'unsafe_unretained'

Tags: iphone, ios, compiler-errors, text-to-speech, ispeech

I'm building iSpeechSDK Beta 3 (released on 2012-05-18) for my sample/test project (iOS Universal app) I just created. I'm getting build time errors.

.....iSpeechSDK/Headers/ISSpeechSynthesis.h:58: error: expected a property attribute before 'unsafe_unretained'

When I double click on the error, it points to the SDK header class: ISSpeechSynthesis.h
..
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id  delegate;
..

PS: I have added the documented linker flag in other linker flags of Build: -fobjc-arc
I tried building for simulator/device/debug/release but all build targets produce same above error.

Please help me resolve this build error.

System/Development configuration-
Mac OS: 10.6.8
XCode: 3.2.5
iOS SDK: 4.2

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong complier. LLVM GCC does not supports Strong and other ARC keywords. Please set your complier as LLVM compiler 4.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ARC is supported in Xcode 3.2.5. I believe it was introduced in Xcode 4.2, but you can try changing your Compiler setting to LLVM GCC 4.2 in 'Build Settings'